# How to increase Wubi virtual disk space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, wubi, disk

I just installed Ubuntu MATE on a separated partition on my Windows 10 machine, but I forgot to select 128Gb as the disk space so it installed the default which is 20Gb, is there any way I can resize the virtual disk to 128Gb through Windows? Cuz I already configured everything and installed my apps, so I don't really want to do it all over again.
[here's the disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wqo3.png)

Comment: Wubi has not been supported since 2012. And it had a limit of 30GB. it was only intended as a temporary test install, which you can now use a flash drive to test to see if you like Ubuntu.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi Windows also now has WSL, version 2 much better than version 1, but know nothing else about it.

Comment: probably you should take a look at GParted. Make a live CD or USB of it and boot up from it and then change the partition size I did it for my Ubuntu 20.04. Another option is (may work) make live CD or USB of Ubuntu mate and resize the partition by booting up from it and then restart. I don't know how to do from windows but I did these steps a week ago to make a shared partition.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guide for resizing the Ubuntu partition that will take you step by step using GParted. But WUBI does have the mentioned limit so if you cannot go past 30GB, this would be the reason why.

https://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/